# Unable to pass payload parameters to Node-RED http request

Tags: node-red

I am trying to do a simple http get request in Node-RED. According to online documentation I have to pass the parameters in a function as input for the http request node. My function looks like this;

```
msg.url = "https://api.socialstudio.radian6.com/v3/posts"
msg.method = "GET"
msg.headers = {'access_token': access_token}
msg.payload = {
        'topics': 234243,
        'limit': 100,
    }
return msg;
```

However when i look at the server response i get the error:

```
["{"error":{"message":"Missing topics parameter.","statusCode":400,"errorCode":"MC-Unknown","requestId":"RnY9E0pbcU1lkiaf"},"meta":null}"][1]
```

I have tried other api's but I have not yet been able to pass the payload parameters.

What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to pass query parameters for a GET request you should set the base URL in the `http request node` and use the mustache syntax to include them:

```
https://api.socialstudio.radian6.com/v3/posts?topics={topics},limit={limts}
```

and change the function node to this:

```
msg.method = "GET"
msg.headers = {'access_token': access_token}
msg.topics = 234243;
msg.limit = 100;

return msg;
```

Comment: How would I go on about if the json was nested? like if `{"topic":{"first":123,"second":456},"limit":100}`

Answer (score 2):

`msg.payload` contains the body of the request, but it looks like the server you're trying to query requires the data to be passed as a query string.

Try this:

```
msg.url = "https://api.socialstudio.radian6.com/v3/posts?topics=234243&limit=100"
```

(and remove `msg.payload`)

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone stumbles upon this question, it's now possible to tell Node-Red to automatically encode payload as query string parameters for a GET request.

First, set the parameters in a `payload` within a `function` :

```
msg.headers = {'access_token': access_token}
msg.payload = {
    'topics': 234243,
    'limit': 100,
}
return msg;
```

Then, add an `http request` node and configure it like this :

[image: request-example]