# Nested elasticsearch GET requests through node-red

Tags: elasticsearch, node-red

I have elasticsearch 6.7 running on a CentOs 7 machine, and I have node-red running from where I try to query the elastic search.

Using the httprequest node (in node-red) works great when I need to POST data to server, or when I need to perform simple GET _search queries where I can simply send parameters in the url, such as :

```
http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:9200/data/default/_search?size={{{size}}}&from={{{from}}}&q=sensor:temp
```

with a simple flow: [image: node-red GET flow]

**As described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42596187/unable-to-pass-payload-parameters-to-node-red-http-request/42597126#comment97686026_42597126).**

But if I need more complex queries that have nested parameters I cannot perform it with parameters through the url.
For example how would I make this cURL GET with the httprequest node in node-red:

```
 curl -XGET "http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:9200/data/default/_search" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
 {
   "size": 0,
   "query": {
     "range":{
       "created":{
         "gte":"2019-03-11",
         "lte":"2019-03-12"
       }
     }
   }, 
   "aggs": {
     "status_terms": {
       "terms": {
         "field": "device.keyword"
       },
       "aggs": {
         "status_stats": {
           "stats": {
             "field": "value"
           }
         }
       }
     }
   }
 }'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that you can send the whole body in the [query string as a parameters](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/common-options.html#_request_body_in_query_string).

It would look like this:

```
curl -XGET 'http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:9200/data/default/_search?source_content_type=application/json&source={"size":0,"query":{"range":{"created":{"gte":"2019-03-11","lte":"2019-03-12"}}},"aggs":{"status_terms":{"terms":{"field":"device.keyword"},"aggs":{"status_stats":{"stats":{"field":"value"}}}}}}'
```

Comment: thank you, it works great! its just `source_content_type=application/json`